# Delphi 2009 classes / components to read/write file permissions

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, ntfs, file-permissions

Does anyone have a set of classes / components that will work with Delphi 2009 (Unicode) to read and write NTFS file permissions?

There was a thing called "NTSet" - but they stopped development at Delphi 2006 about 3 years ago :-(

Any other takers??

Thanks!
Marc

Comment: Also, as for NTSet, I'm a registered user. I used the components with Delphi 2006, and they worked well. I upgraded to Delphi 2007 and they still continued to work flawlessly. Not sure how they will work with 2009 though.

Comment: Since a lot of the core stuff has been made ready for Unicode, the change between versions is probably bigger than between 2006 and 2007, I would think....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[JCL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcl/) has units to deal with file permissions, and they claim D2009 compatibility.

Comment: I believe the best link would be to here: http://blog.delphi-jedi.net/security-library/

Comment: Documentation for the above security library is here: http://jwscldoc.delphi-jedi.net/

Comment: Thanks - I'll see how that library lives up - looks promising!

Answer (score 1):

Colin Wilson's "NT low-level" component set wraps the APIs you need, and supports Delphi 2009 as well as earlier releases.  However you may need to rely on the MS documentation and samples if you need detailed help to implement a specific operation.  You can find the components (and others) at http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/delphi.htm. They are freeware/donationware. I have found many uses for them over the years.

Comment: Colin's stuff is high quality and extremely useful. +1

Answer (score 0):

Although not native Delphi, you could use [SetACL](http://setacl.sourceforge.net/). With that, you have 2 options. You can shell-out and call SetAcl.exe from your Delphi program, or you can use the SetACL.OCX and call it directly from your code.

Of course, you'd need to distribute SetAcl.ocx with your application, but it works very very well.

Comment: As long as their are other ways, I'd definitely prefer a native Delphi way over OCX or shelling out to a EXE - but thanks anyway!