# Delphi creates folder without permissions and owner

Tags: delphi, directory, ownership

I use Delphis ForceDirectories() function to create folders.
Normally, everything works Ok.

Sometimes (randomly, not reproducable), when using the Administrator account, the Folder is created, but not assigned to a User - so I can't access it.

Also, when I try to display the permissions, I get an "Unable to display current owner" message.
Regaining Access by taking the ownership with the administrators account doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide instructions to reproduce

Comment: @David Heffernan Since the error only appeared a few times in the last 6 Months, on different machines, I cannot - sorry.

Comment: Well, I guess you'd better gather some diagnostics then. Pretty hard for any of us to help.

Comment: Maybe the question should be "how can I create a directory without assigning an owner?"

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238183/how-to-create-a-directory-in-runtime-with-full-rights-to-all-users-using-delphi

Comment: What OS/filesystem ? Is it local or connected network drive ? Can several apps try to create same folder at same time ? If you have enough of rights on parent folder, you must be allowed to take ownership and reassign access rights, did you try to do that from Windows UI or from your app ? If you can't get access to the folder from Windows UI, then it is problem with OS, not with app, maybe conflict/bug of low level apps, like antivirus/DLP/... First of all you should find out why you can't change access rights to that folder.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan please give a hint where to get diagnostics and what kind of diagnostics

Comment: @AndreiGalatyn Happened so far on Win2003, Win8, Win7, Win2008, always local Drives.
I have rights on the parent Folder, but can't reclaim it via Windows UI.
Also, deleting the Folder with the App fails.

Comment: @Sam I'll try to use that instead, maybe its better that way, thanks! :)